# How Could This JS Block Be Short-Handed? (JS Refresher)

Tags: javascript, optimization, gsap

I haven't used JS in awhile (2yrs) and I seem to have forgotten some basics;

So my question is: ***How would I clean-up or 'short-hand' the following javascript?***

It would help me out on improving my JS code ( and maybe joggle my brains - LOL ).

```
    var tl = TweenLite.to;

    tl("#container", 0, {autoAlpha:0});
    tl("#header", 0, {top:"-70px"});
    tl("#footer", 0, {bottom:"-180px"});

    function showPage() {
        tl("#container", .2, {autoAlpha:1, delay:.5});
        tl("#header", .2, {top:"0px", delay:.8});
        tl("#footer", .2, {bottom:"-150px", delay:.8});
    } window.onload = showPage;
```

...and obviously I am using [TweenLite](http://greensock.com/) and I am not using jQuery but I am using [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/).  Thnx for your help.

-jason

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tidying up some code, rather than solving a specific problem.

Comment: The topics is about improving code. As per:[http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic] a specific programming problem, or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var tl = TweenLite.to,
    duration = 0.2;

// Set starting states in CSS

function showPage() {
    tl("#container", duration, {autoAlpha: 1, delay: .5});
    tl("#header", duration, {top: "0px", delay: .8});
    tl("#footer", duration, {bottom: "-150px", delay: .8});
} 

window.onload = showPage;
```

You could also check out the [`TweenLite.from`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/from/) method which allows you to do the inverse and set the finished states initially and specify where to tween from.